# Mac stolen in Pakistan

Tags: macbook-pro

My MBA got stolen in Pakistan three weeks ago. I contacted Apple help center to get the location of my device, but they replied that they cannot do anything because the location service is disabled on my Mac, so no one can track the location. But I just learned about WPS tracking on this site in a relevant topic.

Can anyone help me track my device?

Comment: What do you mean by "But I just about WPS tracking on this site in a relevant topic"? And how would this circumvent the disabled location services on your MBA?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to hear about your MacBook Air being stolen.

While there is software built in to macOS and separately available to track, monitor, or lock a device, this software must be installed and turned on ahead of time. Once the device is no longer in your position, there is no way to remotely activate any tracking feature.

If you mean Wireless Protected Setup, this is a feature of Wi-Fi routers to make connecting to the wireless network easier. It would not help you recover your stolen device.

I can't say I know much about Pakistan's laws, but I would recommend providing as much identifiable information about your MacBook Air (serial number, MAC address, proof of purchase, stickers or other external marks) to the local law enforcement. If the device is recovered, I would hope they would contact you.

Good luck.